# How to catch a route and redirect to Another Page in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, middleware

I have a website that I have rebuilt using Nuxt 3. Backlinks exists on numerous platforms and I need the old links to point to the new pages.
Example:
old(website.com/contact.html) new(website.com/contact)

I tried using middleware, but after deploying it, I get this error:
502 Error decoding lambda response

In my middleware/redirect folder I have this:

```
const redirects = [{
    'from' : '/contact.html',
    'to' : '/contact'
}]

export default function (req, res, next) {
    const redirect = redirects.find((r)=> r.from === req.url)

    if (redirect) {
        res.writeHead(301, { Location: redirect.to })
        res.end()
    } else {
        next()
    }
}
```

It works locally but not after deploying to netlify!

and I added this to my nuxtconfig file:

```
    serverMiddleware: [
        '~/middleware/redirect'
    ]
```

I thought that this middleware would act as a net to catch any req to the old contacts.html page and redirect them to the new contact page. but instead it sends that lambda error which I looked around and have not found a solid fix for. I am open to any solution including a different way of redirecting!
Thank you!

Comment: The best would probably be to make the redirects directly on the platform itself (before it even reaches your app) with a rule so that it matches what you had before and what you have now in Nuxt.

Comment: I agree its a better solution to change the links directly. I was just trying to save a bit of time and effort because some of the backlinks are in blogs/articles on other peoples websites.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve redirections without middlewares by using the **`redirect`** option inside `routeRules` in `nuxt.config.ts` as below:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    routeRules: {
        '/contact.html': { redirect: '/contact' },
        '/external-route': { redirect: 'https://example.com' },
    },
})
```

you can also define a new route that can be redirected to any internal or external page.

More rules options can be found here: https://nitro.unjs.io/config/#routerules, which mentioned in the [official doc](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config#routerules)

Comment: Is it possible to reroute multiple pages like so? /contact/** to https://example.com/**

Comment: Do you also know how to keep the query parameters? This way they get lost.

Comment: This is still an experimental feature (at least it says so in the code). This works: "/foo/:id": { redirect: "/bar" } for redirecting all pages to one page, but I can't figure out how to do something like this: "/foo/:id": { redirect: "/bar/:id" }. It just puts ':id' in the address bar.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building your own middleware, you can add your own router options. Here are the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#custom-routes).

1. Create a folder called `app` in the root of your project (same folder as `nuxt.config.ts`.
2. Inside`/app` create file `router.options.ts`.
3. Inside `router.options.ts` write:

```js
import type { RouterOptions } from '@nuxt/schema';

// https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/routeroptions.html
export default <RouterOptions>{
  routes: (_routes) => [
    {
      name: 'contact',
      path: '/contact',
      component: () => import('~/pages/contact.vue'),
      alias: '/contact.html',
    },
  ],
};
```

EDIT:
You could also use `definePageMeta` with `alias`. [Docs](https://definePageMeta).

Comment: Even tho this is a viable solution, it's more of a front-end one (client-side navigation) and not related to server-side/DNS redirections.